# AWSMobileHubHelper DynamoDB AccessDeniedException

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-mobile-hub

I'm using the `Swift AWS Mobile Hub Helper` to build my iOS app and connect to my `DynamoDB` database. I can see that after logging in using a `Facebook SignInProvider` I'm getting an assumed role arn for an authorized role for the table I'm trying to connect to, but when I try to use the load method on my `DynamoDBObjectMapper` I get an error telling like this:

> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource

I tried downloading a new base app from the mobile hub page and making no other alterations but to point it to the new table but it had the same error. My colleague is building an android version of our app and he is able to connect to the database and he says that he made no changes to how he connects so I'm unsure as to what is causing the error.

EDIT: I've been looking at the federated identity pool that I'm ostensibly being assigned and the identity id that cognito is assigning my device (the simulator) is appearing there if I search for it with the dataset that my code is creating.

Comment: I have not used mobileHub but does it required any IAM role?

Comment: Hi, what is the SDK version which you are currently using? Could you upgrade it to the latest SDK from https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/ and see if the error persists?

Comment: I just downloaded a new version off of their website and it's version number (2.4.3) matches the version of mine. Using this base version I can get entries into the default table but I cannot add to or modify these entries, additionally when I point the application toward my custom table I can neither get nor  update entries in the table.

Comment: Also the hub uses a signinprovider to assign a IAM role. The role appears to have full permission to the table Im trying to access and my android colleague seems to be using the same role and having no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For each table in your Mobile Hub app, Hub creates an IAM role policy, and attaches it to the policy your users assume. If you look under your auth/unauth roles for the app (it will have the Mobile Hub project name in it). You should see a list of attached policies. One of those policies will be for the table you created in Hub. If you want that policy to have expanded capabilities, or in your case give access to a different table. You will either need to edit the policy or create a new policy.

Comment: Yeah, and I do have policies for the table attached to the role. It looks like despite indications to the obverse, my application is not actually authenticating correctly with aws.  The database authorization was just the first indication that this was occurring.